# Можно ли связать файловый поток с потоком cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, filestream

Я рассчитывал на то, что `cout` будет выводить всё, что было записано в файловый поток, но этого не происходит.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fstream out("hello_world.txt",ofstream::out, ofstream::trunc);
    out.tie(&cout);
    out << "Hello World!" << endl;
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::basic_ios::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie) это не про это и то, чего Вы хотите добиться реализуется не так просто. Точнее, для этого нет встроенных средств, которые можно использовать не добавляя кода. То, что Вы хотите можно реализовать следующий образом: делаем свой буфер, который можно связывать с несколькими буферами, потом свой поток данных, который будет использовать этой буфер. Выглядеть это может так:

```
class Multibuffer: public std::streambuf
{
public:
    void tieBuffer(std::streambuf* buffer)
    {
        m_Buffers.emplace_back(buffer);
    }

    int overflow(int character) override
    {
        for(auto& buffer : m_Buffers)
            buffer->sputc(character);
        return character;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::streambuf*> m_Buffers;
};

class Multistream: public std::ostream
{
public:
    Multistream(): std::ostream(nullptr)
    {
        rdbuf(&m_Buffer);
    }

    void tie(std::ostream& stream)
    {
        stream.tie(this);
        m_Buffer.tieBuffer(stream.rdbuf());
    }
private:
    Multibuffer m_Buffer;
};
```

И использовать это можно так:

```
Multistream multi;
multi.tie(out);
multi.tie(std::cout);

multi << "Hello World!" << endl;
out.close();
```

Только учтите, что это слишком базовая реализация буфера, в которой нет проверок на `eof` и прочих. Но его можно доработать под Ваши нужды.

Answer (score 7):

Лучше так не делать. Нужно STDOUT перенаправить в файл, запусти программу как

```
program_name > hello_world.txt
```

Но если очень нужно, например для демона, то:

1. открой файл при помощи `::open()` - не стоит использовать `::fopen()`, так как появится головная боль с буферами и их соглосованием.
2. сделай дупликацию дескрипторов при помощи `dup2()`
3. ...
4. PROFIT!

если точнее, то просто продолжаешь пользовать `std::cout` как и раньше, но текст будет попадать в файл. Закрывать уже нужно будет сам файловый дескриптор.

Вот пример:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto fd = ::open("./hello.txt", O_APPEND | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH);

    // Дуплицируем наш дескриптор на стандартный выход
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

    // С этого момента, всё, что попадает в std::cout - попадает в файл.
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    cout << flush;

    ::close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Аналогично можно сделать для `STDERR_FILENO` - стандартный поток ошибок. Он используется `std::cerr` и `std::clog` (первый не буфферизированный, второй, как и `std::cout` - буфферизированный).

Для Windows стоит уточнить поведение и где находятся объявления `::open()` и `dup2()` и их альтернативы:

- [dup/dup2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en_us/library/ms235445.aspx) vs [_dup/_dup2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx)
- [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235491.aspx) vs [_open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) vs [_sopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w64k0ytk.aspx)

Comment: Да, если изначально был вывод при помощи `std::cout`, то не забудьте перед дуплицированием дескрипторов сделать сброс буферов. А то запишется кусок текущего, а потом будете думать - где косяк. И лучше такое делать до любого вывода на консоль.

Comment: честно, я бы наверное написал свой метод который выводил одновременно и в файл и в консоль... Это очевиднее поддерживать чем это. Кстати если надо перенаправление, то не проще использовать `freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);`? Или я не так вопрос понял?

Comment: нет, это я криво вопрос прочитал. @ixSci правильный ответ дал.